# Macro to split number separated by comma into separate numbers in different cells

Tags: vba, excel, split

So I have a string of numbers in excel, each number 1-2 digits but the separated by commas and there can a varying amount of numbers. eg:
eg:

```
       A            B               C 
9, 13, 42, 44  |  1, 18  |  24, 30, 61, 23, 30
```

I would like a macro which takes each line (eg 9, 13, 42, 44) and puts each number i a different cell in the same column - like this

```
9
13
42
44
```

Comment: Take a look at the `Split` function. If you want more help, you need to show some initiative and post your code and where you're stuck.

Comment: Your sample data would overwrite the values below a cell when the sub *'puts each number i a different cell in the same column'*. What do you plan to do to prevent overwrite? Do you mean that hte sample data actually looks like `9, 13, 42, 44 | 1, 18 | 24, 30, 61, 23, 30` ? Showing what you've attempted to solve the problem yourself often explains these small details omitted by your narrative.

Answer (score 2):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub SplitThem()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(Replace(r.Value, " ", ""), ",")
        i = 1
        For Each a In ary
            r.Offset(i, 0).Value = a
            i = i + 1
        Next a
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

Each item falls in the same column as its parent list.

Comment: @Jeeped  Your method of transferring the array to the cells it a little better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to maintain "original" values:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitNumbers()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Worksheets("mySheet").Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| choose your row of interest
        cell.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(Split(cell.Value, ", ")) + 1) = Application.Transpose(Split(cell.Value, ", "))
    Next cell
End Sub
```

if you want to delete "original" values:

```
Option Explicit    

Sub SplitNumbers2()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Worksheets("mySheet").Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| choose your row of interest
        cell.Resize(UBound(Split(cell.Value, ", ")) + 1) = Application.Transpose(Split(cell.Value, ", "))
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeeped: you're right. just laziness. Updated code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

With your data in a series of cells in the first row like this,

[image: split_transpose]
                     <sup>Data before splitTranspose sub procedure</sup>

Run this quick sub procedure that utilizes VBA's [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx) and the worksheet's [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027).

```
Sub splitTranspose()
    Dim c As Long, vals As Variant
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For c = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If CBool(InStr(1, .Cells(1, c).Value2, Chr(44))) Then
                vals = Split(Replace(.Cells(1, c).Value2, Chr(32), vbNullString), Chr(44))
                .Cells(1, c).Resize(UBound(vals) + 1, 1) = _
                  Application.Transpose(vals)
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Your results should resemble the following,

[image: split_transpose_after]
                     <sup>Data after splitTranspose sub procedure</sup>

Comment: Thank  you very much